# Helpdesk software

Tags: customer-service

I want to run a small business website which features helpdesk / customer support software, which includes ticket management, and possibly a knowledge base.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers folks.  After some consideration, I don't think I really need help desk software.  I will just arrange a contact form, so I can later contact them back and arrange service.

Answer (score 2):

[Kayako](http://www.kayako.com/) offers a hosted or self hosted solutions. There is also some open source solutions but I've never used them. I have used Kayako and it's not bad.

OTRS - http://otrs.org/

osTicket - http://osticket.com/

Comment: Kayako is the one used by most webhosters

Comment: Kayako is a bit expernsive for my needs.  Cheers.

Comment: @Steve, that's why I also provided open source solutions also. osTicket has email piping which is a concern based off your comment about Hesk.

Answer (score 1):

[Hesk](http://www.hesk.com/) is free (very small licence fee if you want to remove the powered by tag $40) very feature rich, sold and gets both thumbs up from me.

http://www.hesk.com/

I love it and it ticks all of your requirement boxes

Comment: Very interesting app, thanks for sharing. The only thing that makes me thing it might be not a good option is it's missing support for email piping (automatically creating ticket from e-mails) [ref. http://www.hesk.com/knowledgebase/?article=48] Customers are usually more willing to send ticket via email rather than getting frustarted logging in a ticket system.

Comment: Good point, although it is available as a Public beta. Might be worth testing?

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research on this topic and a well recommended service is provided by: kampyle.com. Its sleek, very professional, easy to integrate and so on. However their rates are rather steep and therefore possible a no-go for smaller businesses (its the reason I didn't opt for them).

Why not opt for a forum / discussion section (possibly password protected). Its easy to setup and you can follow all questions and answer them if needed. Check: vbulletin.com and discussions.zoho.com

Vbulletin has an addition package that might improve your performance: crawlability.com/vbseo/

Answer (score 0):

http://accord5.com/ have a decent free help desk software, although its future is somewhat questionable.

Answer (score 0):

BMC Remedy is probably the most widely used CSR software.  http://www.bmc.com/

It also offers reporting, monitoring, call routing, ticketing, knowledge base, and a slew of other features.  It has both fat client availability and web hosting - and can be synced with Active Directory.