# Need a good, free, light help desk package

Tags: customer-service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Helpdesk software](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9943/helpdesk-software)

I'm launching a new web site that needs a basic help-desk system-- something that will track ticket emails, keep a log, have some basic statistics and possibly power a knowledgebase/FAQ section on my site.

My ideal solution would be hosted (I'd rather not lose a day having to fuss around with installing software on the server), MODERN and CLEAN (read: not feel like it was designed or developed in 1997, which is what I keep coming across) and easy. Simple. Clean. Current. (You know, like the stuff 37signals puts out, or Fog Creek's CoPilot.)

Because we're talking about no more than 10 tickets a week right now, it seems reasonable that I should be able to have the features for free now, to determine if it's right for me. Of course, I'm totally fine with a package that I will pay to grow into, as my needs expand.

If I have to install on my server, it should be Linux based (CentOS).

Zen Desk seems to nail it in the features department but feels like overkill for my (currently, very small) needs.

Comment: This question has been closed because it was asked before and is really not appropriate for this site.  Please read our FAQ, http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq to see what is appropriate.

Comment: Hi Ben-- thanks for the note-- I actually saw that other question but there are far too many open answers, and I felt that adding this question (with more restrictive and explicit parameters with what I am seeking) would be a valuable addition to the community... I respect your decision to close it if you think it's a duplicate though I still believe there is room for both questions here. I am confused when you say it's not the right question for this site. I checked the other stack sites and this seemed like the best fit. Where should I have put it?

Comment: Eric - The issue is that it really is not a great question for any site.  I think the best explanation is this: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/.

Comment: Fair enough. Thx...